# Changing value of a field in javascript for a form submitted in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have a form, which has a notes and a web sub form. On the web, on click on a button Save, value a field say "Test" must be updated to 1. When I click on save for a form submitted on web side the value of the field gets updated, but when I try to click on save (on web side) for a form originated on the notes side, the value doesn't get updated. 
I have used
document.forms[0].TestField.value= "1"

Comment: What is the field type? Editable, computed, computed when composed, or computed for display?

Comment: It is an editable field. I got the solution. Actually I was trying to run the script on the client side, when I changes it to web, it worked.
Thanks!